# STM32 half callback not called

Tags: stm32, dma

I am trying to implement `DFSDM` in `DMA` mode, so I have used `CubeMX` to generate the code and I have configured `DFSDM` `DMA` in circular mode.

Whenever I run the code in debugging mode, I see that inside the `DMA` IRQ handler, it calls `CpltCallback` and not `HalfCpltCallback`.

My Question is why it calls `CpltCallback` and not `HalfCpltCallback`? and how should I handle it?

```c
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_DFSDM1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "\r\nHello\r\n", sizeof("\r\nHello\r\n"), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  uint8_t cr = 1;
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, cr, 1);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      if(flag == 1)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j<taille; j++)
        {
            sprintf(tab, "%05d", (int)val[j]/256);
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, tab, 5, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, ",", 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        }
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "\r\n", 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        flag = 0;
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, cr, 1);
      }
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */

void HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegConvCpltCallback(DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef *hdfsdm_filter)
{
    HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegularStop_DMA(&hdfsdm1_filter0);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin);
    flag = 1;
}

void HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegConvHalfCpltCallback(DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef *hdfsdm_filter)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin);
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin);
    HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegularStart_DMA(&hdfsdm1_filter0, &val, taille);
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you provide a code sample? Maybe take a look at this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you, I have added the code to my post

Comment: Who knows how many errors HAL functions have :)

Comment: I found the solution! My dfsdm initialization passed my DMA mode in normal mode. Now it works